# Is it possible to comment a line from a table?

Tags: org-mode, org-table

Let's say I have the following table :

```
   |--------+--------|
   | Letter | Number |
   |--------+--------|
   | A      | 1      |
   | B      | 2      |
   | C      | 3      |
   |--------+--------|
```

I'd like to only export some part of it. Let's say:

```
   |--------+--------|
   | Letter | Number |
   |--------+--------|
   | A      | 1      |
   | C      | 3      |
   |--------+--------|
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the `org-table-export` function to add a filtering effect. The following excludes rows whose first column matches `"B"` (exact match). The added code is after `;; start of custom filter`, but the rest is identical to `org-table-export`.

Working example:

```
(defun org-table-export-filtered (&optional file format)
  "org-table-export with an added filter based on values in the first column"
  (interactive)
  (unless (org-at-table-p) (user-error "No table at point"))
  (org-table-align)        ; Make sure we have everything we need.
  (let ((file (or file (org-entry-get (point) "TABLE_EXPORT_FILE" t))))
    (unless file
      (setq file (read-file-name "Export table to: "))
      (unless (or (not (file-exists-p file))
                      (y-or-n-p (format "Overwrite file %s? " file)))
          (user-error "File not written")))
    (when (file-directory-p file)
      (user-error "This is a directory path, not a file"))
    (when (and (buffer-file-name (buffer-base-buffer))
                 (file-equal-p
                    (file-truename file)
                    (file-truename (buffer-file-name (buffer-base-buffer)))))
      (user-error "Please specify a file name that is different from current"))
    (let ((fileext (concat (file-name-extension file) "$"))
            (format (or format (org-entry-get (point) "TABLE_EXPORT_FORMAT" t))))
      (unless format
          (let* ((formats '("orgtbl-to-tsv" "orgtbl-to-csv" "orgtbl-to-latex"
                                "orgtbl-to-html" "orgtbl-to-generic"
                                "orgtbl-to-texinfo" "orgtbl-to-orgtbl"
                                "orgtbl-to-unicode"))
                 (deffmt-readable
                     (replace-regexp-in-string
                      "\t" "\\t"
                      (replace-regexp-in-string
                       "\n" "\\n"
                       (or (car (delq nil
                                          (mapcar
                                           (lambda (f)
                                             (and (string-match-p fileext f) f))
                                           formats)))
                           org-table-export-default-format)
                       t t)
                      t t)))
            (setq format
                    (org-completing-read
                     "Format: " formats nil nil deffmt-readable))))
      (if (string-match "\\([^ \t\r\n]+\\)\\( +.*\\)?" format)
            (let ((transform (intern (match-string 1 format)))
                    (params (and (match-end 2)
                                   (read (concat "(" (match-string 2 format) ")"))))
                    (table (org-table-to-lisp)))
              (unless (fboundp transform)
                (user-error "No such transformation function %s" transform))

            ;; start of custom filter
            (let* ((org-table-temp (org-table-to-lisp))
                   (new-org-table-temp '()))
              (while org-table-temp
                (setq row (car-safe org-table-temp))
                (setq row-text (format "%s" (car-safe row)))
                (if (bound-and-true-p row-text)
                    ;; change "B" below to filter on different value
                    (if (string= row-text "B") nil (push row new-org-table-temp))) ;; appends if not matching
                (setq org-table-temp (cdr org-table-temp)))
              (setq new-org-table-temp (nreverse new-org-table-temp))
              (setq table new-org-table-temp)
              )
            ;; end of custom filter

              (let (buf)
                (with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect file)
                    (setq buf (current-buffer))
                    (erase-buffer)
                    (fundamental-mode)
                    (insert (funcall transform table params) "\n")
                    (save-buffer))
                (kill-buffer buf))
              (message "Export done."))
          (user-error "TABLE_EXPORT_FORMAT invalid")))))
```

This works by taking original table produced when executing `org-table-export`, checking value in first column of each row for `"B"`, and if it does not match appends row to a new filtered table.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the original table as input to a source block that produces the table you want to export. Then it's just a matter of *not* exporting what you don't want:

```el
* Original table                                      :noexport:
 #+name: orig
 |--------+--------|
 | Letter | Number |
 |--------+--------|
 | A      |      1 |
 | B      |      2 |
 | C      |      3 |
 |--------+--------|


* New table
#+begin_src elisp :var tbl=orig :exports results
  (progn
    (setf (nth 2 tbl) nil)
    (delete nil (append (list 'hline (car tbl) 'hline) (cdr tbl))))
#+end_src
```

Comment: Thanks. A bit laborious, but I guess there is no simple way to do it...

Comment: You can just copy the original table into the `New table` section and just delete the row. That's equivalent to what the source block does and might be less work.